# Allow HTML content for ToolTip in Enyo

Tags: javascript, enyo

I am working on Tooltip, where my requirement is to show more details line by line inside tooltip, when user hovers over some iconbutton. Currently, I am trying like this:

```
{kind: "moon.TooltipDecorator", components: [
                    {kind: "moon.IconButton", src: "$lib/moonstone/samples/assets/icon-button-enyo-logo.png"},
                    {kind: "moon.Tooltip", name:'info', floating: true, contentUpperCase: false,allowHtml: true, content: "Floating tooltip <br>for an IconButton."}
                ]
}
```

But this is treating HTML content just like strings. I tried to set dynamically, but result is same. Below what i tried:

```
this.$.info.setContent('Fare Charges'+ "<span style='border:1px solid'"+flightsData[0].price+'</span><br>'+'<span>Some more data</span>');
```

Is there any ways to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

moon.Tooltip was designed to only be a single line of text. If you want more than one line, you can create your own tooltip based off of moon.Tooltip.

```
enyo.kind({
    name: 'my.Tooltip',
    kind: 'moon.Tooltip',
    published: {
        allowHtml: false
    },

    allowHtmlChanged: function() {
        this.$.client.set('allowHtml', this.allowHtml);
    },

    create: function () {
        this.inherited(arguments);
        this.allowHtmlChanged();
    },

});

enyo.kind({
    name: "App",
    components: [
        {kind: "moon.TooltipDecorator", components: [
                    {kind: "moon.IconButton", src:   "$lib/moonstone/samples/assets/icon-button-enyo-logo.png"},
                    {kind: "my.Tooltip", name:'info', floating: true, contentUpperCase: false, allowHtml: true, content: "Floating tooltip <br>for an IconButton."}
                ]
        }
     ]
});

new App().renderInto(document.body);
```

You also need to override the .moon-tooltip-label CSS class:

```
.moon-tooltip-label {
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: If you're using a newer Enyo you could also just set up a binding from `allowHtml` to `the $.client.allowHtml`